# Add an element to a list at an index that is out of range in python 3

Tags: python, arrays, list

In other languages, such as javascript, when you add a value to an array that is outside of the range of indexes you "extend" the array with undefined values until the specified index.

Example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3]
arr[4] = 4
console.log(arr) // [1,2,3,undefined,4]
```

When I try to do this in Python, I get a list assignment index out of range error.

Is there a way to do the same thing in Python?

Comment: i think it's more akin to dictionaries, i.e. `d = {5: 5}`

Comment: If your intention is to have a mapping from integers to integers, it would be better to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) than a list. Dictionary keys can be integers, and you can assign to any key at will (`d[9000] = 5`).

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass `list` and override the `__setitem__` method so that it will extend the list as required by the given index, which could also be a `slice` object, in which case the larger of the `start` and `stop` attributes of the slice should be used:

```
class List(list):
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.extend([None] * ((max(index.start, index.stop - 1) if isinstance(index, slice) else index) - len(self) + 1))
        super().__setitem__(index, value)
```

so that:

```
arr = List((1, 2, 3))
arr[5] = 5
print(arr)
arr[7:9] = [4, 5]
print(arr)
```

outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, None, None, 5]
[1, 2, 3, None, None, 5, None, 4, 5]
```

Note that the expected output in your question in incorrect because an index of `5` actually refers to the 6th, rather than the 5th, item of the list.

Comment: Good catch on the indexing, I fixed my question

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_list.append(None)
my_list.append(5)
```

Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, None, 5]

???
I may be misunderstanding the problem, but